# Which libraries are loaded by default in pry?

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

When I use `Tempfile` class in `pry`, I don't use require it.

```
% pry -f
pry(main)> Tempfile
Tempfile < #<Class:0x00007fb5121149b8>
```

But when in `irb` I must to require `tempfile` first.

```
% irb
irb(main):001:0> Tempfile
NameError: uninitialized constant Tempfile
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0> require 'tempfile'
=> true
```

So it seems `pry` load some libraries by default.
Which libraries are actually loaded?

This is my environment

```
 % ruby -v
ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247) [x86_64-darwin17]
 % irb --version
pirb 0.9.6(09/06/30)
 % pry --version
Pry version 0.11.3 on Ruby 2.4.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to $LOADED_FEATURES, which can be a bit excessive, consider:

```
Gem.loaded_specs.values.each {|s| puts s.name}
```

which only lists gems with specs

```
[20] pry(main)> Gem.loaded_specs.values.each {|s| puts s.name};nil
did_you_mean
coderay
method_source
pry
io-console
vls
=> nil
```

BTW, in this example, I had loaded the vls gem manually.

Answer (score 7):

You can compare `$LOADED_FEATURES` to see everything that's loaded in a default `pry` session vs an `irb` session (or a plain ruby script).

The short answer is that Pry loads whichever libraries it needs to provide its own behaviour. The long answer is too long (and too likely to get out of date, or differ between versions) to list here -- better to ask your current environment.

It's good practice not to rely on other libraries to load their dependencies for you, because those dependencies can change. (Though in cases like this, it can be hard to notice you're missing a `require`, because everything still works.)

Comment: Just to add to that, the latest version of `pry` (at the time of writing) also depends on the `coderay` and `method_source` gems. So the full list of loaded libraries also depends on whatever the current version of *those* gems happens to use. All of which may also be dependant on the current ruby version, and ruby interpreter.

Comment: So my summary would be (1) Who cares what's auto-loaded? Always assume nothing is loaded by default, and you'll be fine. `require`ing the same dependency multiple times is not an issue; in fact, it will do *nothing* the second time. Use `load` if you really want to forcibly re-require a dependency. (2) If you really do care, it's best to just check `$LOADED_FEATURES` rather than looking at some StackOverflow post/similar, since that information will almost certainly go out of date.

Comment: @TomLord I assume the answer to (1) is the inverse: "I was happily using Tempfile not realising it needed to be required; what else do I need to be similarly cautious about?"; unfortunately I don't think there's a good solution to that (excluding "just remember" and "look up every seemingly-built-in constant you use").

Comment: Bottom-line, If its not part of the **core** library, you should be requiring it including **standard** library scripts. Relying on any other "automatic" behavior from a third party script/gem which could change at any moment outside of your control is not the best way to write robust code. If everything requires its own dependencies without relying on others, then there is nothing to ever worry about.